# TensorFlow Installation Problem MacOS Ventura

Tags: tensorflow, pip

I've been having a problem when I tried installing TensorFlow. I have installed numpy, pillow and pygame with pip, but I can't install TensorFlow. I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 on an M1 macbook. I am currently running python 3.11.3.

I have already tried reinstalling Python and pip. I keep getting this error when I try to install Tensorflow:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: Your python is probably too new, try using Python 3.10

Comment: I installed 3.10, but I got the same error. I also tried it with 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

You can install TensorFlow in Mac OS using Anaconda Navigator.

Please follow the below steps:

- Step 1 : Install the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download) CLI for Mac M1 (at bottom of the page)
- Step 2 : Visit - https://brew.sh and copy and paste the command code in terminal - enter login password - enter (installing will be invisible as no activity)
- Step 3 : Type> **cd downloads** (in terminal)
- Step 4 : Type> **bash** **Anaconda3-2023.03-1-MacOSX-arm64.sh** (downloaded_anaconda_filename.sh) - enter
  (yes to license - enter to accept default location)
- Step 5 : cd \ (to go back to default location)
- Step 6 : (To create conda Virtual Environment, Type - )

> conda create --name tfVirEnv 
> conda activate tfVirEnv

- Step 7 : (Now install TensorFlow in VirEnv)

> pip install --upgrade pip
> pip install tensorflow #or
> conda install tensorflow

- Step 8: (Verify if TensorFlow installed correctly, Type - )

> Python
> import tensorflow as tf
> tf._ _ version_ _

- Step 9: Now you can open the Jupyter notebook through Anaconda Navigator application or can simply type below code in terminal

> conda install notebook
> jupyter notebook

Please have a look at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) for the reference. Thank you.