# tensorflow no t installing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've tried to install tensorflow with:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

put I recieve the following error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

my python version is 3.11.4 and pip 23.1.2

tensorflow is supporting python 3.11 so why is it not installing?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: mac os mojave, but that shouldn't be a prolem

Comment: It is probably a bug, in any case there isn't sufficient information to identify the cause. And I doubt anyone here can help you, you would have a bigger chance to file an issue on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow, but replies there tend to be slower than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Actually your Mac OS version **IS** a problem, since it seems the oldest Mac OS release that has wheels is 10.15, which is newer than the version you have. Just check: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.13.0/#files

Comment: but i can install other things with pip, like pytorch, no problem. It could be that python 3.11.4 is to new for tensorflow, but I don't want to downgrade python just for this

Comment: @JonasFredriksson no, 3.11 is not "too new for tensorflow", TF officially supports 3.11 version. As Dr.Snoopy said - "just check https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.13.0/#files " and you'll see olders Mac is 10.15

Comment: I couldn't find the `.whl` file in the `Package location` table in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) tutorial. I suggest you to either use docker or install another python version along your current one. It's not that hard & doesn't require you to uninstall your current python installation. I know it should be supported but I couldn't find the `.whl` link. It could also be about x86 vs M1. Could you verify which one you have? Discussion [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/60209). Nightly build could have this already.

Comment: x86, ok,  maybe I stick to pytorch for a whlie

Comment: Hi @Jonas Fredriksson, Please try again by using command `pip install tensorflow` as I am able to install tensorflow 2.13.0 with python 3.11 in Mac OS(Darwin). Please have a look at this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76283180/21904865) to install tensorflow in Mac OS which might be helpful. Let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: still same error: jonas@Jonass-MacBook-Pro:~$ pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: @JonasFredriksson, Could you please try again by following the steps and commands mentioned in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/)?

Comment: If you are referring to the link that describes an anaconda install then I am sorry, I don't want to install an virtual environment for this. Essentially all I want is that pip3 install tensorflow would work, but since this is not the case I will stick with sklearn that did install using pip.